# BeforeScenarioBlock to execute only before "Given" statement

Tags: bdd, specflow

Based on SpecFlow [documentation](http://www.specflow.org/documentation/Hooks/), the `[BeforeScenarioBlock]` hook will be called before "Given" and "When" statement. Is there any way to make the `[BeforeScenarioBlock]` hook only to be called before "Given" statement ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `[BeforeScenarioBlock]` will run before any 'block' in the scenario, ie before each separate set of `Given`, `When` or `Then` blocks.  There is no built in way to specify that a hook should only run before a particular type of block I don't think but I believe it should be straight forward enough to make sure that the code only runs before specific blocks inside the hook code. Something like this:

```cs
[BeforeScenarioBlock]
public void BeforeScenarioBlock()
{
    if (ScenarioContext.Current.CurrentScenarioBlock == ScenarioBlock.Given)
    {
        //execute the code before the given
    }
}
```

Although I have not tested this.